# Angular drag&drop lists with buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I need to develop an angular component for re-sorting objects (dragging from list 1 "source" to list 2 "target"), and I need the component to have buttons.

I have observed the various dnd components existing at the [Angular Material website](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview), the "Drag&Drop connected sorting" is a good base for what I'm looking for. What I still miss are the buttons that we've used to have back in the days (I know, old fashioned, but these are mandatory requirements).

The requested buttons are:

1. button between the two lists, to move a selected item from list 1 to list 2 or vice versa, [see illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tadh5.png)
2. &  3. "up" and "down" buttons next to the target list, in order to move a selected item up or down

I know this sounds weird but that's what they demand and I need to deliver. I suppose I could write such component from scratch but it'll be much nicer if there's anything out there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Spätzle, forget for a moment the ability to "drag and drop". How you change the position of elements of two array? Solve this problem (usually using splice) and, after, add the drag and drop. Remember, drag and drop between list it's only use the mouse to interchange elements form two arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the HTML that the example uses (there's 1 root div per array, you can insert a 3rd div in between using material icon buttons) and use the `transferArrayItem` function to transfer the items back and forth.

Some pseudo code. The gist is: 
 * Get a reference to the 2 containers, look through the API for the right object.
 * Use `ViewChild` to get access to it in your TS file.
 * Have clicking on the items select them and store their index in `selectedLeft` and `selectedRight`

```
 @ViewChild('left-container') leftContainer;
 @ViewChild('right-container') rightContainer;

 public selectedLeft: number;
 public selectedRight: number;

 moveRight() {
  transferArrayItem(this.leftContainer, this.rightContainer, this.selectedLeft, 0);
 }
```

This should move the item at the selected index to the top of the list on the right.

Comment: Robin, it's unnecesary get reference to the containers. The drag a drop is for interchange elements of two arrays using the mouse. If you don't want to use the mouse to drag, simply change the array as usually you do it